# General term for a series of matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

A and B are two non-zero square matrices such that ${A^2}B=BA$ and if $(AB)^{10} = {A^k}{B^{10}}$ then the value of
k is?

**Attempt:**

Tried solving for lower powers of $AB$ and observing a pattern

$AB=AB$

$(AB)^{2} = {A^3}{B^{2}}$

$(AB)^{3} = {A^7}{B^{3}}$

$(AB)^{4} = {A^{15}}{B^{4}}$

The series follows a pattern $(AB)^{n} = {A^{2^n-1}}{B^{n}}$.

Hence $(AB)^{10} = {A^{1023}}{B^{10}}$

Is there any general method to obtain the $n^{th}$ term without inspection of initial values?

Comment: If $A=B=0$ any $k$ is good

Answer (score 1):

Now that you know what the answer is, try induction.  $$(AB)^{n+1}=(AB)^n(AB)=A^xB^nAB$$
So you first need another induction to find
$$B^nA=A^yB^n$$